# astropy.table writing problems

Tags: python, ascii, astropy

I'm having problems to write astropy.tables, since yesterday when I updated to astropy 4.0, I cannot write tables into files.

I even tried to copy the examples in the [astropy web](https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/io/ascii/index.html)  like:

```
import numpy as np
from astropy.table import Table, Column, MaskedColumn
from astropy.io import ascii

x = np.array([1, 2, 3])
y = x ** 2
data = Table([x, y], names=['x', 'y'])
ascii.write(data, 'values.dat')
```

and I always get the same strange error:

```
ValueError: Data type <class 'astropy.table.table.Table'> not allowed to init Table
```

Anyone have an idea of what could be happening? 
Sorry for the vague question, but I really do not understand why even the examples of the web are failing...

NOTE: I'm using python 3.7.3 on anaconda, in a Mac OS 10.14.6.

> UPDATE:

After two downgrades and upgrades **the problem resolved itself**... 
I still don't know what happened but it's no longer

Comment: Can you please post the full traceback?

Comment: I just tried it and it works for me. Perhaps something went wrong in your update.

Answer (score 0):

After two downgrades and upgrades the problem resolved itself... 
I still don't know what happened but it's no longer displaying that odd behaviour.
Thanks in any case!